Flow embedded on Public Page in Experience Cloud Site - Guest User cannot see certain fields
4 fields - First name, Last name, Phone and Email - are missing on my public page (the flow is embedded on the Home page of my experience cloud site, and the Home page is public (no login required))
The 4 fields exist in my Screen

No fancy settings on these fields

...

When I debug with Survey Site Guest User, I see the 4 fields

When I go to public page, I don't see the 4 fields. I only see these other fields that are below the 4 fields on the same Screen element

In Builder, here's what the Home page (public) looks like

I did find a User: Survey Site Guest User
(/survey is in the url of my site, I figure this is the right one)
... and the User has profile: Survey Profile
On this Profile, I setup FSL, Record Type / Page Layout. On the Page Layout, I added all the fields I expect to see as a guest user.
I'm stumped. I think my knowledge of Visibility and Access for Site Guest User is lacking. Please advise.

I figured it out. I was modifying the wrong Flow above. I'm in a legacy Org with a ton of band-aid fixes, and they have 2 Flows named almost exactly the same, and they do nearly the same thing. I was modifying the one named after the team I'm supporting.
I figured this out by going to Builder, then to the page where the Flow is embedded. I clicked on the Flow from the embedded component there. Before, I was going to Setup > All Sites. Lesson learned :|
I thought about deleting this post, but people can still learn from it in a few ways.
